# XML not being found or Created

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace Students
{
    public partial class StudentDetails : Form
    {
        public StudentDetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument studentXML = new XDocument("students")

            if (File.Exists("\\SR\\SR\\Student Records\\students.xml"))
            {
                 studentXML = XDocument.Load("\\SR\\SR\\Student Records\\students.xml");

            }
            else
            {
                studentXML = new XDocument(new XElement("students"));

            }

            ParameterPassing.studentNo = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter Student Number", "Student Number");

            XElement xml = new XElement("student");
            xml.Add(new XElement("StudentNo", ParameterPassing.studentNo));

           if (studentXML.Descendants().Count() > 0)
            {
                studentXML.Descendants("students").First().Add(xml);
            }
            else
            {
                studentXML.Add(xml);
            }
            studentXML.Save("\\SR\\SR\\Student Records\\students.xml");
        }

        public void CreateDatabase()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("\\SR\\SR\\Student Records\\students.xml");

            dgvMembers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I have no errors with my code, it just doesn't open create or open the XML document.

I made one by hand to see if that worked but that had no effect either.

Could somebody possible help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Where exactly does your `students.xml` file exist beforehand, and where do you expect it to end up? (You're currently looking for it and saving it in your process's working directory.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The full directory path is `\\SR\\SR\\Student Records\\students.xml` I've added that in sorry. It doesn't work still even with the full file path.

Comment: So `SR` is in the root directory of the drive containing the working directory of the process?

Comment: @JonSkeet no, the directory is a USB so the drive changes.

Comment: Well you're not specifying a drive in your path...

Comment: @JonSkeet so, you want me to specify a drive which will not always be the same for the file path? Not to mention that I queried people with the exact same syntax without a drive and theirs works perfectly and they have no idea why mine's isn't.

Comment: The path you specify will be treated as being relative to the working directory of the process. If that's on a different drive, you need to specify the drive. It's not clear how you're running the code at the moment - if the working directory *is* on the same drive, then I'd expect this to be working. But you can't specify a directory and just hope that it'll guess the right drive. I've no idea what you mean by "I queried people with the exact same syntax without a drive"

Comment: @JonSkeet just as I said, I asked numerous people who had the same code as me i.e. No drive specified and they work. Update: Adding a directory works but this program will not necessarily run on the drive I am working from so how would you recommend I go about making it so it will work?

Comment: That still doesn't tell us how *they're* running the code and how *you're* running the code. Sounds like you may want to enumerate the drives with `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` and find one with the expected directory on it...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
        XDocument studentXML = new XDocument("students");

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                string XMLFilePath = String.Format("{0}{1}", drive.RootDirectory, "SR\\SR\\Student Records\\students.xml");
                if (File.Exists(XMLFilePath))
                {
                    studentXML = XDocument.Load(XMLFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
```